# Change Dataset access database Visual Studio

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, ms-access

I've created a windows application with connected to an access database. Now I am re-using my code and project for a new application, and need to change the database for the new Access database, different columns and all.

Is there any way of replacing it on my project? I changed it in properties but can't see the dataset in my Forms to change at all. Will I need to go 1 by 1?

Comment: Please post your code.

Comment: My question is exactly that, is there anyway of doing a full replacement of the datasets without resorting to code? (any visual studio wizard functionality or something of sorts)

Comment: A lot of code may depend on database column names and datatypes.  You can change a/your data connection to use the new access database, but I do not see that being successful becase of the aforementioned code dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

Right click on data connections in the server explorer, select add connection.  Your installation may default to Sql Server, click the `Change` button to the right of `Microsoft SQL Server (SqlClient)` and select `Microsoft Access Database File (OLE DB)`.

Comment: Thank you but that is not my question. It doesn't seem there's a feature in Visual Studio to do this easily.